# What to use instead of a list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I'm just getting started with Haskell and finished a nice [exercise](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/mgs-appsem-exam.pdf) to make a Caesar cipher.

One of the first steps was to make a function that will take a letter and turn it into a number. I know that chr and ord can do this already but part of the exercise was to write your own.

```
let2num c = head [ b | (a,b) <- zip ['a'..'z'] [0..25], a==c]
```

I'm new to the Haskell syntax and one of the first things I learned was list comprehensions, so that has become my hammer. I'm very curious though, what is another (likely better) way to write this function?

If you're curious the rest of the cipher is in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/796430).

EDIT

I'm also interested in other ways to translate back from numbers to letters.

```
num2let d = head [ a | (a,b) <- zip ['a'..'z'] [0..25], b==(d `mod` 26)]
```

Comment: I wonder if `head [ b | (a,b) <- zip ['a'..'z'] [0..25], a==c]` is O(2n+1).

Comment: @Yasir: Strictly speaking it's O(1), since there are only 26 lower-case letters. But yeah, it's not terribly efficient. See my answer.

Comment: @Roman: But it first creates a zipped list, then creates another list of elements satisfying `a==c`, then extracts an element: quite a lot of work to consider it O(1), huh. :-) I may be wrong though.

Comment: @Yasir: asymptotic complexity does not depend on anyone's subjective judgement. If it takes bounded number of steps, then it's O(1). And your judgement is still not precise: lazy evaluation (particularly, lazy construction/consumption) make it perform different actions than it might seem on the first sight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution:

```
import Data.List
let2num c = let (Just n) = elemIndex c ['a'..'z'] in n
```

Or:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
let2num c = fromJust $ elemIndex c ['a'..'z']
```

Or in [pointless style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree):

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
let2num = fromJust . (flip elemIndex) ['a'..'z']
```

The function `elemIndex` returns the index of the first element in the given list which is equal (by `==`) to the query element, or `Nothing` if there is no such element.

The `Maybe` type encapsulates an optional value. A value of type `Maybe a` either contains a value of type `a` (represented as `Just a`), or it is empty (represented as `Nothing`). Using `Maybe` is a good way to deal with errors or exceptional cases without resorting to drastic measures such as error.

The function `fromJust` extracts the element out of a `Just`.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I'll need to do some googling to figure out what everything means, but this is very helpful.

Comment: Any thoughts on the reverse process? When going from a number back to a letter I don't think elemIndex would help.

Comment: I see why they named it `fromJust` as opposed to `unJust` ;)

Answer (score 4):

The reverse process:

```
num2let = (!!) ['a'..'z']
```

`!!` is a [List index (subscript) operator](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/libraries/base-4.3.0.0/Data-List.html#v%3a-33--33-), starting from `0`. It is an instance of the more general `Data.List.genericIndex`, which takes an index of any integral type.

`(!!)` is [partially applied](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application) here, which means it still needs one argument of type `Int` to yield the result (a value from the list whose index equals to `Int` value you pass to `num2let`).

Comment: That is awesome! Unfortunately I could only accept one of your answers :)

Comment: strictly speaking, yes, as was the original (see Roman's comment).  But if you mean this should be more efficient than the original, not noticeably, because you're still traversing a linked list.  If you want to have the same number of steps for converting '0' as '25', you'll need a different data structure (I would use an array).

Comment: Or in section notation: `num2let = (['a'..'z'] !!)`

Answer (score 3):

“Caesar simply replaced each letter in the message by the letter three places further down the alphabet, wrapping around at the end of the alphabet.” We can simply write it in Haskell. In fact we can avoid `let2num` and `num2let` altogether.

So let's start with defining a table to map plain text alphabet to the cipher text alphabet:

```
cipher = let abc = ['a'..'z']
             code = drop 3 abc ++ take 3 abc
         in  zip abc code
```

It will look like

```
[('a','d'),('b','e'),('c','f'),('d','g'), ... ]
```

Now we can encrypt a symbol, if we simply `lookup` the letter in this dictionary:

```
ghci> lookup 'a' cipher
Just 'd'
```

`lookup` returns a `Maybe Char` value, we need to convert it to simply a `Char`, and for this I use `maybe` function, using `'?'` for symbols which were not found in the cipher, and `id` (identity function = no changes) to found symbols:

```
ghci> maybe '?' id (lookup 'a' cipher)
'd'
```

Now we can write an `encrypt` function to encode just one symbol, it will leave missing characters, like a space, unencrypted:

```
encrypt c = maybe c id (lookup c cipher)
```

To encrypt an entire string:

```
ghci> map encrypt "haskell is fun"
"kdvnhoo lv ixq"
```

So we can put it all together:

```
encrypt c = maybe c id (lookup c cipher)
  where
  cipher = let abc = ['a'..'z']
               code = drop 3 abc ++ take 3 abc
           in  zip abc code
```

Comment: I read that you want to write `let2num` function and assumed that you want it to implement the substitution cipher. I wanted to show that the cipher can be implemented without explicit calculation of the ordinal numbers, but rather with a translation table.

Comment: Yes, the end goal was a substitution cipher, but if you read the whole question, you'll notice that the actual question was essentially "What's a better way to write num2let from scratch, without chr and ord?)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, I think somebody should mention that list comprehensions are just a shortcut for writing stuff in the list monad. Your code transcribed is, roughly, this:

```
let2num c = head $ do (a,b) <- zip ['a'..'z'] [0..25]
                      if a == c then [b] else []
```

Not a very interesting example, but there you go.

Also, de-sugaring the do syntax, this is the same:

```
let2num c = head $ zip ['a'..'z'] [0..25] >>= \(a,b) -> if a == c then [b] else []
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are opposed to the `ord` solution. List-based solutions perform unnecessary work (traversing a list). And they still are desugared into invocation of the `enumFromTo`, a method of the `Enum` class which allows to convert between `Int`s and `Char`s in the same way as `ord`/`chr` do. This is the lowest-level interface provided for `Char` type, so you hardly can "write your own" here (apart from doing boxing/unboxing yourself, but this is not a big joy).

Comment: @Yasir: they *do* work for Unicode, since `Char` is simply a Unicode code point. E.g.: `ord 'ы'` -> `1099`

Comment: @Roman: Hehe indeed, quite forgot `Data.Char` is Unicode-aware.

Comment: @Roman - I think the OP is opposed to `Ord` because this is homework.  If you can't use `Ord` and don't want to traverse a list, I think the best option would be an immutable array.  But it's a contrived problem and solution.

Comment: She said it was part of the exercise, so let's not bother arguing what's already been decided, eh?

Comment: I'm not at all opposed to the ord/chr solution, I was simply following the instructions for the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the following:

```
import Data.Char

caesar :: Int -> Char -> Char
caesar n c = if isAlpha c 
             then chr (ord 'a' + (ord c - ord 'a' + n) `mod` 26) 
             else c
```

and `map (caesar n)` over the string with `n` the desired offset.

Comment: If you read the question, I think you'll find your answer, while clever, is somewhat tangential to the question lashleigh actually asked.